# How to load image from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to load the image URL from my NSMutableArray.
Here is my Code:

```
id path = (NSString *)[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"icon"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
```

If I use: id path = @"http://www.xzy.de/icon.png"; it´s all right, but not if I want to extract the imageURL from my Array

Anyone who can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: In your first line you're casting to NSString. If you know it's type, then you might as well use that as the variable type. `NSString path = [[stories …] …];`

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the second line and find out the value of path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's the solution to the problem:

```
path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
// that's a tab in the next line's string
path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Any idea why that was necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you declare `path` as anonymous `id` type. Define it as NSString. Shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: If I do so,I get following error:


2010-03-28 13:38:32.816 Presentation[52185:20b] *** -[NSConcreteData dataWithContentsOfURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d0d1a0
2010-03-28 13:38:32.816 Presentation[52185:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData dataWithContentsOfURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d0d1a0'
2010-03-28 13:38:32.817 Presentation[52185:20b] Stack: (
    ...
)

Comment: That error.... is completely unrelated to the type declaration.  Here, you're trying to use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` on an instance of NSData instead of on NSData itself.